# How to create aPDF document from the current screen with all tableview data present?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf-generation

I have one `UIViewController` then in this viewcontroller are two `UIView` or One `UITableview`. One view are on top & second are on bottom. `UITableview` are on centre With many cells & table view data are not fix. So I don't know how to generate a pdf with whole view or also show all tableview data with in one pdf & these pdf are also access by user in his phone also. Please help me guys..

Comment: is a snapshot good enough from the `tableView` ? Is there some different formatting between pdf and the `tableView`'s layout?

Comment: yes its same as tableview & its show all data is enough for me

Comment: Check out this library on `GitHub` , there is a pretty good sample project with `UITableViews`: https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/PDFGenerator

Comment: this library minimum sdk 8 but my app supports 7

Comment: are you using swift?

Comment: yes i am using swift